# Processing AJAX returned object JSON

Tags: jquery, json, each

Ok this is weird. Im using PLUpload and it has a `onComplete` function that returns a variable called `info`. Here is what it returns in Chrome Dev Console.

```
Object {response: "[{"id":"65","series":"","part":"","title":"","subt…,"file":"","product":"","type":"1","status":"2"}]", status: 200}
```

```js
var response = $.parseJSON(info['response']);

$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
   $.each(value, function(k, v) { 
       console.log(v);
    });
});
```

`console.log(value)` gives me this in Chrome Dev Console:

```
Object {id: "69", title: "", ogv: "", webm: "", length: "0:12"…}
```

I can turn down the arrow and see all of my elements. So I thought doing a `$.each` on `value` would produce anything but the `console.log(v)` echos  out nothing.

But if I do `console.log(value['id'])` I get 65. So that works.

Why can't I iterate through this object with the `$.each` function?

Comment: Because there is only one dimension: object with properties, which are scalars. You don't have nested objects or arrays to iterate over them using your second loop.

Comment: works for me with caveat, I had to fix syntax errors in object posted. Keep in mind most of the fields you show have empty string for values  http://jsfiddle.net/w7CZw/

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? it is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N5XZJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$.each** can not iterate over given object because you are use **length** as a key and that is also javascript method and  this is a jQuery Bug that $.each doesn't use [**hasOwnProperty**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method

[jQuery .each Bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5499) also mentioned [`here`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/21)

so better use core javascript  [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) method with **hasOwnProperty** check

```
var op = { "id":"69", "title":"", "ogv":"", "webm":"", "length":"012" };
for(var i in op) { 
    if(op.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         console.log(i + ':' + op[i] + '\n');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be considered a bug in jQuery, but the object you are iterating over has a `length` property.  Evidently, `$.each` uses `length` for the purposes of iteration.  You're better off using `for..in`.

Comment: check with `object.hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` is used to iterate over collections (arrays). You are trying to iterate through the properties of an object. This is done with the `for..in` loop.

```
var response = $.parseJSON(info["response"]);

$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    for (property in value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(property))
            console.log(property + " -> " + value[property]);
    }
});
```

Edit:

Also, the server is returning an array with one object in it. If you know you are receiving only one object every time, this can be simplified to:

```
var value = $.parseJSON(info["response"])[0];

for (property in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(property))
        console.log(property + " -> " + value[property]);
}
```